# Routing to reflect global state

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My router currently looks like this

```
{
            path: 'map',
            component: MapComponent,
            children: [
                { path: 'live',  component: LiveTripComponent },
                { path: 'drivers/:id',     component: DriverDetailComponent },
                { path: 'customers/:id',     component: CustomerDetailComponent }
            ]
        },
        { path: 'drivers', component: DriversPageComponent },
        { path: 'customers', component: CustomersPageComponent },
        { path: 'accounts', component: AccountComponent 
}
```

There is a global date range, which can be changed from any page. 
How can I capture global state in url so that refreshing the link wont change the global state.

I thought of using `aux` route
`{path: 'range', outlet: 'aux', component: RangeComponent}`
and passing date range as queryParams.

I run this when date range gets changed

`this.router.navigate(['../', '/aux:range'], {relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: {asd: 'dsa'}});`

this changes the user to

`http://localhost:3000/map/live(aux:range)?asd=dsa`

But clicking on any link, aux route info gets removed from url.

Is there a way to get this working.

Comment: As far as I know queryParams are supposed to stay until you explicitely remove them in the new router (beta.2 from Angular RC.4)

Comment: i am on rc4. Is the order of adding aux route RouteConfig important, or probably this.router.navigate(..) is wring. What should be the [routerLink], I am not sure.

Comment: I didn't talk about aux routes. Aux routes support is still quite limited and I haven't experimented a lot with it yet because of the limitations.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can this be done by creating a root route and having the current routes as its children

Comment: "this" means what in your last comment?

Comment: "How can I capture global state in url so that refreshing the link wont change the global state"

Comment: I haven't tried myself yet but I saw it mentioned that queryParams are global and should be kept when you navigate using routerLinks

Comment: is it mandatory to have global state in URL. You can create a service for that inject it in AppComponet and maintain state there. Where you need to access that state you can inject the service

Comment: @Siraj I am doing that.. but refreshing the page would clear these global state. Hence, need to keep them tied to url